# Since regsvr32 does not have a path parameter where to register the dll, where is a regsvr32 registered dll to be found?

Tags: registry, regsvr32

Visual Studio Setup projects allow you to install dlls and add registry keys to Windows registry, by specifying the path where to put them.

When I opt to register a dll manually, using regsvr32.exe, given it does not have any parameter that specifies the path where to add them in the registry's tree, where are regsvr32 registered dlls to be found in the Windows Registry tree, after all ?